# Getting list of triangles from polygone

Tags: python

I have created two classes named `Point` and `Triangle` and I have a function `pts_polygone` that gives me the list of points in a polygon.

For example `PolyPts = pts_polygone(Point(0., 0.), 9, 4)` gives me a polygon of 9 points, centered in `O(0, 0)` and of radius 4.

I'm trying to triangulate this polygon, but first I have to extract the list of triangles, and I'm almost there but one is missing, here is what I have:

```
def tri_polygone(PolyPts):
    O = Point(0., 0.)
    TriLst = []
    for i in range(len(PolyPts)-1):
        P2 = PolyPts[i]
        P3 = PolyPts[i+1]
        TriLst.append(Triangle(O, P2, P3))
    return TriLst
```

The last triangle is missing, to make it a 'circle' if you get what I mean. I know there's something wrong with my dimensions in the list I create, it is of len 8 instead of 9, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last triangle should consist of the first point, the last point in `PolyPts` and the origin, right? So you can do the following:

```py
def tri_polygone(PolyPts):
    O = Point(0.,0.)
    TriLst = []
    for i in range(len(PolyPts)):
        P2 = PolyPts[i]
        P3 = PolyPts[i-1]
        TriLst.append(Triangle(O,P2,P3))
    return TriLst
```

That way you append 9 points, origin, current point `i` and the point behind `i`. Python has the nice feature that you can pass negative indices to lists, which means you read the array starting from the end, i.e. `PolyPts[-1]` is the last point, `PolyPts[-2]` is the second last point and so on.

Comment: Nice, using the fact that `-1` is the last element. Slicker than my solution :)

Comment: Yes that's exactly it ! Thank you very much for this very simple solution !

Answer (score 0):

You are looping "around" the polygon on couples of points. The first with second, second with third, etc... For this, you are rightfully looping on `range(len(PolyPts)-1)`. But that means that you never get to the last point ***inside*** the loop. Because you are going "around" the polygon, the last point should couple with the first, so ***just add this line after the loop***:

```
TriList.append(Triangle(O, P3, PolyPts[0]))
```